# Substitute for Nestle Semisweet Chocolate Chips in Australia?

Tags: chocolate

I am living in Australia and having a hard time finding a good substitute for Nestle semisweet chocolate chips. What should I look for in a good quality semi-sweet chocolate chip in Australia and where can I find them?

Comment: You say you're "having a hard time"... does that mean you've already tried a couple of brands? If so, which brands have you tried and what do you find unsatisfactory about them?

Comment: Just use any old chocolate chips, there's nothing special about nestle's product.

Answer (score 3):

Semi sweet equates to our garden variety dark choc chips in Australia. If like me You're wanting a bit more of a cocoa hit try looking for 70% cocoa cooking chocolate or choc chips. I know Aldi get them from time to time and our Super IGA gets them so I'm guessing the other supermarkets will maybe have them or try european style delicatessens for them.

Comment: I might go for the "bit more cocoa hit" but that (as you've said) is not going to be a direct substitute for Nestle's ho, hum, middle of the road, perfectly ordinary chocolate chips ( with a heavy dose of marketing. ) So long as I've avoided "chocolate flavored chips" (a horrid product that appeared for a while in the USA) I've been quite satisfied with "generic" chocolate chips as being the same exact product, with less marketing to pay for.

Answer (score 2):

My mother in law has had the same troubles as she uses the nestle semi sweet morsels for chocolate crack cookies. The cookies just don't crack the same with other chocolate chips. She tells me it is due to the quality of the cocoa butter. She has experimented and found a half-half mix of cadbury dark choc chips and milk chocolate chips does the job.

Comment: That makes semi sweet chips just deconstructed. Makes Sense. But Nestle does taste a bit more bitter than the Cadbury. But Cadbury is more creamy don't know if it has to do with the butter or not. But I am pretty sure there is no semi sweet in Australia unless you get them from a USA import store. At least we haven't found anything close. From a American living in Australia.

Answer (score 0):

Costco Semi sweet chocolate chips come close and does the job for me.